# onClick anchor tag a current div display using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on Image gallery here I want onClick anchor tag  current image display in .gallery-container is not working. Previously on image `img` click, I got the output `.gallery-column img`.

```
$('.gallery-column img').on('click', function(){
    var expandImg = document.getElementById('expandedImg');
    expandImg.src = this.src;
    expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    var imageCaption = $(this).next("div").html();
    $("#expandedImgCaption").html(imageCaption);
});
```

This code is working fine. Now I have added anchor  it is not working.
 I have tried but unable to achieve.

Can anyone suggest me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carouselImg = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-img');
  $('a.post-carousel').on('click', function() {
    var expandImg = document.getElementById('expandedImg');
    var carouselImg = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-img');
    expandImg.src = carouselImg.src;

    expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    var imageCaption = $(this).next("div").html();
    $("#expandedImgCaption").html(imageCaption);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1066px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-row {
  width: 52%;
  max-height: 497px;
}

.gallery-column {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.gallery-column img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

#expandedImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrap">

  <div class="gallery-container" style="display: block;">
    <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
      <img id="expandedImg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="carousel-img">
      <div class="img-caption">
        <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery-row">
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542646822891-0a8451fce513?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=181de57e88385f8f32f48aef4e2831f9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>olor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542632890661-441e6f424098?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=60444a082924abcdc72901abaa800620&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542635521008-f80f4d69bad4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a6e7baa2e8b1e236090d116d35bf0855&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>nsectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be simply achieved using the `this` keyword to target the related `.carousel-img`.

**NOTE 1:** You've missed to attach the id `expandedImgCaption` to the `img-caption` of `expandedImg`:

```
<div id="expandedImgCaption" class="img-caption">
```

**NOTE 2:** You don't need the `next()` since the div is inside the anchor not next of it :

```
$("#expandedImgCaption").html($('.img-caption', this).html());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.post-carousel').on('click', function() {
    $('#expandedImg').attr('src', $('.carousel-img', this).attr('src')).parent().show();
    $("#expandedImgCaption").html($('.img-caption', this).html());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1066px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-row {
  width: 52%;
  max-height: 497px;
}

.gallery-column {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.gallery-column img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

#expandedImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrap">

  <div class="gallery-container" style="display: block;">
    <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
      <img id="expandedImg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="carousel-img">
      <div id="expandedImgCaption" class="img-caption">
        <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery-row">
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542646822891-0a8451fce513?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=181de57e88385f8f32f48aef4e2831f9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>olor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542632890661-441e6f424098?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=60444a082924abcdc72901abaa800620&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542635521008-f80f4d69bad4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a6e7baa2e8b1e236090d116d35bf0855&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>nsectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using *this* like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carouselImg = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-img');
  $('a.post-carousel').on('click', function() {
    var expandImg = document.getElementById('expandedImg');
    expandImg.src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    var imageCaption = $(this).find('.img-caption > h3').text();
    $('.gallery-container').find('.img-caption > h3').text(imageCaption);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.gallery-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1066px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-row {
  width: 52%;
  max-height: 497px;
}

.gallery-column {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.gallery-column img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

#expandedImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrap">

  <div class="gallery-container" style="display: block;">
    <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
      <img id="expandedImg" class="img-caption" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="carousel-img">
      <div class="img-caption">
        <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery-row">
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542648108-66d2937f4bcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5ebbcae6a8310fd61d8a9fc82b79c792&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>Still more than 2 Millions+ people using</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542646822891-0a8451fce513?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=181de57e88385f8f32f48aef4e2831f9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>olor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542632890661-441e6f424098?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=60444a082924abcdc72901abaa800620&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-column">
      <a href="#" class="post-carousel">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542635521008-f80f4d69bad4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a6e7baa2e8b1e236090d116d35bf0855&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" class="carousel-img">
        <div class="img-caption">
          <h3>nsectetur adipiscing elit. Donec</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: img-caption is not changing.